# How to run a python script once per minute, but stop upon a condition?

Tags: python

I have a python script that generates a random number and shoves it in variable "randomnumber". If the randomnumber is equal to 100, then it stops. Is there a way I could just do:

python "randomnumber.py" and the contents execute every 10 seconds until I kill the script or if randomnumber is equal to 100 (will use sys.exit())?

Comment: That would be a fairly trivial script. Do you have an attempt you could show us?

Comment: Use a while with randomnumber != as condition, and a sleep inside it. After the wile sys.exit()

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will run main every 10 seconds until it generates a 100 from a random number between 0 and 100 (inclusive).

```
import time, random

def main():
    #code goes here

while random.randint(0, 100) != 100:
    main()
    time.sleep(10)
```

Comment: I think the break condition is 100

Comment: Hmm, technically you're correct. I'll make it randrange(0, 101) and he'll have a 1 in 101 chance I guess. He didn't specify a minimum.

Comment: Also, `randint(0, 100)` produces random integers between `0` and `100` (inclusively)

Comment: Oh does it? I must be really unlucky because I couldn't roll a 1 using "0, 1" for params. Ill edit.

Comment: @user161778 Gotta keep rolling ;-)